# How to make value state text always visible

Tags: sapui5

I wonder is there is a way to display value state text of the control even when this control is not focused.

The default functionality is to display this text only when the control is focused.

I searched info on this for a couple of hours with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can prevent it from hiding by overriding the onfocusout function

```js
  oInput.openValueStateMessage()
  oInput.onfocusout = function() {
    InputBase.prototype.onfocusout.apply(this, arguments);
    this.openValueStateMessage();
  }
```

https://jsbin.com/zebuvot/edit?js,output

the sample also illustrates that there is a problem with having the value state text shown all the times. It covers the input control below

thanks